# Cannot understand why program crashes when it reaches this part in the code

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opengl-es, imagebutton

Seems to crash whenever it reaches "startBtn"

I am currently using Java in Eclipse with the Android SDK and would really appreciate your help

Below is the code for the MainMenu Class:

```
package com.pandagame;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainMenu extends Activity 
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        Log.d("MainMenu", "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        /** Fire up background music */
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Fire up music");
        Engine.musicThread = new Thread()
        {   
            public void run()
            {
                Intent bgmusic = new
                Intent(getApplicationContext(), Music.class);
                startService(bgmusic);
                Engine.context = getApplicationContext();
            }
        };
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Engine.MusicThread");
        Engine.musicThread.start();
        Log.d("MainMenu", "new Engine");
        final Engine engine = new Engine();
        /** Set menu button options */
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Set Menu button options");
        ImageButton startBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.start);
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Step 1");
        ImageButton exitBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.exit);
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Step 2");
        startBtn.getBackground().setAlpha(Engine.MENU_BUTTON_ALPHA);
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Step 3");
        startBtn.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(Engine.HAPTIC_BUTTON_FEEDBACK);
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Step 4");
        exitBtn.getBackground().setAlpha(Engine.MENU_BUTTON_ALPHA);
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Step 5");
        exitBtn.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(Engine.HAPTIC_BUTTON_FEEDBACK);
        Log.d("MainMenu", "Step 6");
        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                Log.d("MainMenu", "onClick");
                /** Start Game!!!! */
                Intent game = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Game.class);
                MainMenu.this.startActivity(game);

            }
        });

        exitBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) 
            {
                boolean clean = false;
                engine.onExit(v);
                if (clean)
                {
                    int pid= android.os.Process.myPid();
                    android.os.Process.killProcess(pid);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Other Classes include:

```
Background.java
Game.java
Engine.java
Music.java
PandaActivity.java
Screen.java
```

"start" and "exit" are both .png files which are located in the res/drawable folder

Comment: Post the logcat please

Comment: hmmm, use ImageButton's id's which you have added in xml layout instead of drawable. find imagebutton as `ImageButton startBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.start);`

Comment: -1 for crash without stacktrace

Comment: I have tried your ImageButton startBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.start); idea but it just comes up as an error. Just so you know the "start" part of (R.drawable.start) is a .png and is refering to a picture.And also it does get past this part when it compiles. It crashes when it hits startBtn.getBackground().setAlpha(Engine.MENU_BUTTON_ALPHA);

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to refer ImageButtons with  drawable id

i.e

```
 ImageButton startBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.start);
```

`findViewById`  needs id of the view to refer it.

you should use

```
 ImageButton startBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.start);
```

Comment: I have tried your ImageButton startBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.start); idea but it just comes up as an error. Just so you know the "start" part of (R.drawable.start) is a .png and is refering to a picture. And also it does get past this part when it compiles. It crashes when it hits startBtn.getBackground().setAlpha(Engine.MENU_BUTTON_ALPHA);